# How to get array of objects that have same name as name from other array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have one array that looks like this:

```
  this.firstArray =  [{
                "activityCode": "10",
                "activityDisplayname": "Evidencija",
                "smoduleCode": "UOM_RECORD_COMPONENT",
                "label": "Evidencija",
                "invalid": false,
                "component": "VpnEvidencijaUslugeComponent",
                "icon": "fa fa-puzzle-piece puzzle",
                "disabled": false
            }, {
                "activityCode": "11",
                "activityDisplayname": "Pregled",
                "smoduleCode": "UOM_VIEW_COMPONENT",
                "label": "Pregled",
                "invalid": false,
                "component": "OrderOverviewComponent",
                "icon": "fa fa-check-circle circle",
                "disabled": false
            }, {
                "activityCode": "12",
                "activityDisplayname": "Provjera",
                "smoduleCode": "UOM_CHECK_COMPONENT",
                "label": "Provjera",
                "invalid": false,
                "component": "ValidationComponent",
                "icon": "fa fa-check",
                "disabled": true
            }]
```

And i have other array that have some specific values but structure is same as first one. Now what i want is to return array of objects that have same `activityDisplayname` in both array. I tried something like this but this is with fixed `activityDisplayname`

```
  let item = this.confing.filter(function(item) {
        return item['activityDisplayname'] == 'Provjera';
      });
```

Now i need to change this 'Provjera' with that second array. Any suggestion?

I created method isCommon():

```
isCommon(ac:string){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.confing.length; i++) {
        if (this.confing[i]['activityDisplayname'] == ac) {
            return this.confing[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(this.confing,'sta je nasao')
}
```

and then i have this:

```
if(this.confing[this.active]['newOrder']){
          let item = this.confing.filter(function(item) {
          array =  this.isCommon(item['activityDisplayname']);
          });
```

but im getting error:

> Property 'isCommon' does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: define a function like `isCommon(ac: string)`, then change your filter to return this: `isCommon(item['activityDisplayName'])`. In that function check if this exists in the second array or not.

Comment: @mok i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionBy

```
let arr = _.intersectionBy(arr1, arr2, 'activityDisplayname');
```

Comment: im using angular 2 how to use _.intersectionBy ? im getting an error

Comment: add lodash library npm install lodash --save

Comment: const intersectionBy = require('lodash/intersectionBy');
intersectionBy(arr1, arr2, 'activityDisplayname');

Comment: i cannot include any librieries thats that problem...its restricted area :)

Comment: :-) mm you can look how they implemented it and take from them :-)